# C++ vector bounds checking

Tags: c++, vector, bounds

I have a 6D vector and I need to check neighborhood of each element (2 elements in each direction). Of course when I am on boundary of the vector, check leads in the Segmentation fault. All I can do is having switch with ton of cases. Is there any better way to solve this? I also thought of something like try-catch.

Comment: A 6D vector? Jesus...

Comment: Yeah I know, but there is no other way to do it.

Comment: Something like a 6D vector sounds like a weird concept, which could probably improved by segmenting an appropriate 1d in memory space appropriately.

Comment: Or perhaps breaking it up or abstracting it away into classes might make working with it easier and less error-prone.

Comment: This 6D vector represents 6D space for my planning software. It is probably  possible to break it into smaller pieces, but then it would be much harder to program it.

Comment: Use `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to access your elements.  Second, don't mask your bugs by using `try/catch` -- actually fix them.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I don't know what bugs are you talking about. This isn't bug, and I can't use try/catch even if I wanted to (because it isn't exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still too bulky but it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> Vector1D;
typedef std::vector<Vector1D> Vector2D;
typedef std::vector<Vector2D> Vector3D;
typedef std::vector<Vector3D> Vector4D;
typedef std::vector<Vector4D> Vector5D;
typedef std::vector<Vector5D> Vector6D;
typedef std::array<size_t, 6> Path;

bool GetVectorPathElement(Vector6D const &vector6D, Path const &path, int &val)
{
    size_t i = 0, k = path[i];
    if (vector6D.size() > k)
    {
        Vector5D const &vector5D = vector6D[k];
        k = path[++i];
        if (vector5D.size() > k)
        {
            Vector4D const &vector4D = vector5D[k];
            k = path[++i];
            if (vector4D.size() > k)
            {
                Vector3D const &vector3D = vector4D[k];
                k = path[++i];
                if (vector3D.size() > k)
                {
                    Vector2D const &vector2D = vector3D[k];
                    k = path[++i];
                    if (vector2D.size() > k)
                    {
                        Vector1D const &vector1D = vector2D[k];
                        k = path[++i];
                        if (vector1D.size() > k)
                        {
                            val = vector1D[k];
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Invalid path " << k << " at index " << i << std::endl;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Vector1D vector1D = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    Vector2D vector2D = { vector1D, vector1D, vector1D, vector1D, vector1D };
    Vector3D vector3D = { vector2D, vector2D, vector2D, vector2D };
    Vector4D vector4D = { vector3D, vector3D, vector3D };
    Vector5D vector5D = { vector4D, vector4D };
    Vector6D vector6D = { vector5D };

    Path path = { 0,0,2,1,4,5 };
    int element;

    if (GetVectorPathElement(vector6D, path, element))
    {
        std::cout << "Path: ";
        for (auto i : path)
            std::cout << i << " ";

        std::cout << "\nElement value at destination: " << element << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/nL1zo2